# EF7 How to have two entities pointing to the same table

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am just wondering how to have two different entities in a data context access the same table in a database. Each entity has a different set of columns that it uses.  The application is .NET 7 console using EF Core.

I have tried to put each entity in a different namespace and am using attribute notation rather than fluid notation (a rough example follows):

```
namespace bob {
   [Table("sourceTable")]
   public class bobTable { [key] public keyColumn .... and other fields}
   }
}

namespace fred {
  [Table("sourceTable")]
   public class fredTable { [key] public differentKeyColumn .... and other fields}
   }
}
```

Basically, I am using the first entity to move data between the same table in two different databases, then the second entity is updating some columns.

I originally had just the one entity, however, it has some columns marked as NotMapped.  I found that when doing the update of the columns post copy, saveChanges was returning correct number of entities updated, but nothing was being written out to the database.

There is a new primary key column in the target table, and in the single entity this is marked as notmapped to prevent a *column can't be null* error.  Thinking this is the cause of the update not working, I am trying to add a second entity which has the appropriate mapping.

When doing so I get:

> 'Cannot use table 'sourceTable' for entity type bobTable as it is
> being used for entity type fredTable'

I was thinking of using *Entity Splitting* to try and resolve the issue, but was wondering if anyone else has some thoughts.

Comment: If they are two separate databases then why not use two separate DbContexts? Mappers like Automapper/Mapster/Mapperly etc. can handle copying/constructing a destination instance from the source.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered this, and it may be the solution.    I was hoping to avoid creating a static dbContext for one table-subset, however, it is still probably a viable solution at present.